# Python - OS High Sierra - NSPlaceholderDate Error

Tags: python

I have been searching for answers to why my mac mini running OS High Sierra keeps throwing this error:

```
objc[18808]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork()...
```

I currently have 15 scripts that are essentially the same, just for a different ID and running through cron. This issue seems to stem from running this mac OS version along with multiprocessing in python. I've found several threads saying to use

`export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`

So this works oddly ONLY if I enter it in to the console. So to make it work I have to: ssh into my mac mini, enter in the export line above, and then run the scripts. When I try to let Cron handle it, I'm still seeing that error pop up in the logs. I've added that export line to my ~/.bash_profile, entered it in and even checked my env - all of which say that is present in my environment. Yet I'm getting this error no matter how I try to run the scripts right now.

I have tried adding this to my scripts:

```
os.environ["OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY"] = "YES"
```

but this has not helped. It also doesn't work if I do not enter in that export line manually - I am guessing somehow that line is not being applied to the right environment?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this help: https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! So started searching on how to set the environmental variables for cron and you can do so just by simply editing with **crontab -e** and then adding the line:

```
OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```